# How can I reliably detect if a Hard Drive is corrupted?

Tags: windows-10, clone, filesystem-corruption, acronis-trueimage

My boss is concerned that I inadvertantly corrupted a hard-to-configure source hard disk while doing a disk clone.

I do not believe the drive is corrupted, as it seems to function perfectly in every regard, however I need to justify this belief to my boss as the application is safety-critical. Part of the doubt is that Acronis True Image gave an error upon clone completion, even though when tested, the destination drive worked correctly.

My experience is that either clones fail or they work perfectly. Also, the source drive is very unlikely to be corrupted during a clone. Are these fair assumptions?

How can I determine this definitively?

Platform is Windows 10 Pro, but I would be interested in approaches for any OS environment.

Thank you!

Response to comments:
The error said "The disk clone has failed." Maybe not word for word but very similar generic error. Will update with exact wording if I do the clone again.

My boss believes the data may have been altered because the OS's on both drives became very unstable during testing. I realized later this was because I had removed some grounding tape while taking out the drive, and replacing the grounding tape fixed the issue on both drives.

Comment: Run SMART tests on both drives?

Comment: `gave an error upon clone completion` is not very helpful.

Comment: Would help if you can share the error.

Comment: Why does your boss believe that the data on the disk was altered during cloning?

Comment: @FrankThomas, and others, I have addressed your questions as an edit in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobWaters "the OS's on both drives became very unstable during testing. I realized later this was because I had removed some grounding tape while taking out the drive, and replacing the grounding tape fixed the issue on both drives." you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill We are not sure if the drive was damaged during the testing, even if it appears to work correctly. That's why I want a test that will verify independantly it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a sha256 checksum for ALL files on the disk.
The only issues are:

1. Comparing them will take a lot of time
2. If you boot either image after cloning some bits will change

Thus after cloning you have to immediately do the sha256 comparison, and not boot either drive.

Thus if ALL the sha256 match the files are the same.

Comment: Good answer.  I am guessing that one or more of the checksums already came up bad because of the "clone error" OP referenced.  Clone tools should be check-summing (is that a word?) files (or the image as a whole) or they aren't good clone tools.

Comment: As a general rule clone tools don't change the files.  I have used DRBL and probably clonezilla has an option, but I have never used it.  My images have always been fine.

Comment: Agreed sir.  "My images have always been fine.".. me too.. except when the clone tool itself tells me there was an error (like OP had).

Comment: Well, then I suggest using DRBL and selecting the sha256 option, but this will SLOOOW down the cloning process significantly.  I know other file comparison software exists, but I don't have any recommendation for this particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the reasoning of your boss for assuming that you corrupted the source disk for a copy operation knowing that a backup operation involves only read operations on the source drive?

> My experience is that either clones fail or they work perfectly. Also, the source drive is very unlikely to be corrupted during a clone. Are these fair assumptions?

Your backup operation probably disclosed problems with your source drive as your backup operation tried to read from sectors of the drive that are not read out during normal use. You find similar issues on this site when searching for the program Rufus. People claim Rufus is destroying their USB drive. In reality it discloses problems of the target drive as lots of information (a big image file) is written in a short period of time using up a lot of space on the pendrive.

> How can I determine this definitively?

You would need to verify sector readibility and file system integrity as you did not disclose the copy mode you were using in Acronis True Image: Files or partitions, used space or full sector by sector copy...

1. Run smartmontools and post your log file here.

You find a description how to compile a log file here:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10910

2. Depending on the parameters shown in the log file you should either duplicate your source drive or search for unreadable sectors. The easiest way is to do this from a linux pendrive filled with Knoppix, systemrescueCD or others.
   the basic syntax is like
   `ddrescue infile outfile mapfile`.
   `infile` and `outfile` can represent partitions and drive as well as files. You would need to run that command on your disk. The mapfile will show unreadable sectors in a coded but readable form.

If it is about verifying readability of the input drive the output target is discarded using `/dev/null` as outfile.

3. Running chkdsk on the source disk

Running chkdsk on the soure cannot be reversed. If you doubt that your source disk is dammaged make sure that a duplicate is available before invoking chkdsk.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning couldn't have damaged *the hard drive*, ie. the physical device. Reading a disk to be cloned and writing to a disk that you're cloning to is no different than any other disk operation. That means that chance of accidentally damaging the disk is no bigger than when copying a file (adjusted for the amount of data being cloned, of course). While it's possible that the drive will die during cloning, in such case it would also die very soon under normal operation. It's not the cloning that causes the event, but drive's condition.

Disk's physical condition can be checked by reading its SMART parameters. SMART is a diagnostic data collection system built into the disk. Most importantly reallocated sector count and pending sector count should ideally both be 0. If any of these parameters is larger than zero, the drive should be considered not completely reliable. If it's in the thousands, it's a ticking timebomb.

If SMART looks okay, then the disk isn't damaged (well, save for external mechanical damage, like the tape you've mentioned).

Then there's the logical damage, ie. corruption of the structures on disk: the partition table and filesystems. In other words the bytes can be read and written correctly, but their values don't make sense or are inconsistent. Such corruption could be already present on the source disk, introduced when handling the image, or occur when writing to target disk (although more sophisticated cloners like Acronis True Image would detect the first case unless cloning sector-by-sector is enabled). This is also what would happen if cloning to a partition smaller than the source, but if I remember correctly True Image will detect that too.

A decent partition editor should tell you if there are any problems with the partition table. For example GParted, which is free and can be started eg. from an Ubuntu USB, will warn you about any potential problems when starting up. If it gets to the main window without additional dialogs, then the partition table is fine. Then look for warning or error icons next to displayed partitions. If there are any, right-click the partition and select *Information*. (Latest versions of GParted will show an error next to FAT partitions if some system packages are missing - it's not an indication of a problem with the partition and can be ignored.)

Finally, the filesystem on a partition could be corrupted. For NTFS it's best to use Windows's `chkdsk` or its graphical counterpart to check for filesystem consistency. Some of such problems can be repaired by these tools.